# Transforming XML to slightly different XML belonging to different version of same schema

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb, mule

I need to transform one XML (say x1.xml) which is the input to my application to a slightly different XML(say x2.xml) format which is based on the newer version of same schema. x2 is the output from my application. About 90% of elements of x1 and x2 are same as they belong to same schema (just different versions).

What will be the best approach for transformation. I am using java and mule esb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bread and butter task for XSLT. Start with an identity template rule that by default copies elements across unchanged:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then add further template rules for any elements you want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the documents, type of transformation required, and amount of times you are going to run it. You need to weigh the cost of learning the choice technology against the benefit it is going to provide.

I personally would start with an xslt stylesheet or the Java DOM api because that's what I am familiar with. If the performance does not meet your requirements switch to one of the other choices that will.